getting error while parsing malloc.h data structures in gdb
malloc.h included in code file.
have compiled with multiple ways like
gcc -g -gdwarf-4 -o heap_test  heap_test.c
gcc -g -o heap_test  heap_test.c
etc
each time getting following error
(gdb) p mp_
'mp_' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type
(gdb) p main_arena
'main_arena' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type
Both are part of malloc.h
GDB version
gdb heap_test
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2-19.el8
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=d0bbbf371048ee8aa8a30c03b189cb268b8ad9e4;hb=refs/heads/release/2.38/master
Here is my code :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

        char *b0, *b1, *b2, *b3, *b4, *b_large;
        // main arena blocks

        b0 = malloc(0);
        memset(b0, 0xaa, 0);
    
        b1 = malloc(8);
        memset(b1, 0xaa, 8);

        b2 = malloc(16);
        memset(b2, 0xbb, 16);
        return 0;
}

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8b8) at heap_basic_test.c:11
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
11              b0 = malloc(0);
(gdb) n
Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8b8) at heap_basic_test.c:14
14              b1 = malloc(8);
(gdb) p mp_
'mp_' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type
(gdb) p arena_main
No symbol "arena_main" in current context.
(gdb)

Debug path is "/usr/lib/debug/"

Please edit your question and show the code that generates the errors.

try also -g3 to have more debug data available

malloc.h has been deprecated since the last millennium. Unless some internal header of your lib is also called malloc.h for some reason.

-g3 still not working.

Tried <stdlib.h> also getting same error.
